# Change widget contents when a screenshot is being taken

Tags: android, android-widget

Is it possible to detect when a screenshot is being taken and change the display of my app's widget to hide private information? I'd like to add that as an option for my app but can't find how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can! In your widget service, register a `BroadcastReceiver` with the intent `android.intent.action.SCREENSHOT`. It will trigger out every time you make a screenshot. Then execute your method there to hide the data or change the widget at your taste.